# Behaviour:filename.htc not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

This is the link that shows box-shadow and border radius working in all ie versions. But when i do the same it wont work. Here is the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/harmeet_jaipur/H9GqS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTC is a long dead technolegy, I wouldn't recommend going there.
If you need to support older IE versions, either simply don't put shadow in these browser as it's eventually just cosmetics, or use IE specific filter:

```
  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#eeeeee, Strength=15, Direction=90),
```

See here:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Comment: Great thanks. I never had an issue with HTC, only recntly been facing problems. Wont use in the future now.